# Не происходит добавление элементов в двунаправленный список

Tags: c++, алгоритм, списки

Имеется часть кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct queue {
    int inf;
    queue *next, *prev;
};
void addElements(queue *begin, queue *end);
void showQueue(queue *begin, queue *end);
int menu();
void input(int &a);
int main() {
    queue *begin = NULL;
    queue *end = NULL;
    while (true) {
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter the element:" << endl;
            addElements(begin, end);
            cout << "Element added" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            showQueue(begin, end);
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "Press Enter if you want to exit" << endl;
            if (_getch() == 13) {
                delete begin;
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Choose 1-4 or 0" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void addElements(queue *begin, queue *end) {
    int inf;
    input(inf);
    queue *t = new queue;
    t->inf = inf;
    t->next = NULL;
    if (begin != NULL) {
        t->prev = end;
        end->next = t;
        end = t;
    }
    else {
        t->prev = NULL;
        begin = end = t;
    }
}
void showQueue(queue *begin, queue *end) {
    cout << "Choose the way you want to show the queue:" << endl;
    cout << "1 - from begin to end" << endl;
    cout << "2 - from end to begin" << endl;
    int choise;
    input(choise);
    queue *temp;
    cout << "--------------Queue--------------" << endl;
    switch (choise)
    {
    case 1:
        temp = begin;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << "\t\t" << temp->inf << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        temp = end;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << "\t\t" << temp->inf << endl;
            temp = temp->prev;
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Choose 1 or 2" << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int menu() {
    cout << "1 - add element" << endl;
    cout << "2 - show queue" << endl;
    cout << "0 - exit" << endl;
    int choise;
    input(choise);
    return choise;
}
void input(int &a) {
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (cin.good()) {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Задача - добавление элементов в двунаправленный список и вывод их на консоль. Однако при выводе списка показывает, что список пуст. В чем ошибка в функции добавления элементов и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В передаче по значению. Ваши переменные `begin` и `end` в `main` не изменяются - в функции вы передаете их копии, так что всякие `begin = end = t;` выполняются над *копиями*.

Передавайте по ссылке (типа `void addElements(queue*&begin, queue*&end)`).

Сам код на предмет ошибок не рассматривал; начните с этого.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу хочу сказать, что Вам нужно также определить и реализовать метод `deleteQueue(queue *&begin, queue*& end)`, где будет удалена динамическая память, выделенная под очередь.

Comment: Dershov, такая имеется, просто сюда не весь код копировал